# Including External Headers in Header Files in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm attempting to learn CMake by building a small application using CMake and SFML in Visual Studio. However, I am having difficulties pointing my `.hpp` files to where my SFML headers are. It seems like CMake doesn't consider header files as targets, so it is not adding these external include directories to my headers. Therefore, I can't use the SFML modules in my headers to define classes and whatnot. Here is my `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(Euclid)

set(SFML_INCLUDE_DIR "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\SFML\\include")
set(SFML_LIBRARY_DIR "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\SFML\\lib")

set(SRC
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Block.cpp
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Block.hpp
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Main.cpp
)

add_executable(Main ${SRC})

target_include_directories(Main PUBLIC ${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(Main PUBLIC ${SFML_LIBRARY_DIR})
```

Comment: "*it is not adding these external include directories to my headers*". What does that mean exactly? Header files are never built in isolation so which cpp file is actually failing? Please show the exact build log and errors.

Comment: You should use [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) then you can just link to smfl target and cmake will do the rest

Comment: When I try to `#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>` in `Block.hpp` Visual Studio says it cannot load the file. But this works in the `cpp` files.